# Update excel file base on the output from textarea

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My code imports the excel file then put a certain column in to a textarea
I want to know how would i modify the excel file if for example i edited something on the textarea that edit should be saved on the excel file

```
String excelFilePath = "sample.xlsx";
                FileInputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                Workbook workbook = null;
                try {
                    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row nextRow = iterator.next();

                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                    Iterator<Cell> scellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

                    cellIterator.next();
                    scellIterator.next();
                    scellIterator.next();
                    Cell topicsCell = cellIterator.next();
                    Cell topicSentimentCell =scellIterator.next();

                    String cellContents = topicsCell.getStringCellValue();
                    String scellContents = topicSentimentCell.getStringCellValue();

                    String[] topics = cellContents.split(";");
                    String[] topicSentiment = scellContents.split(";");

                    ArrayList<String> tpc = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<String> topicsents = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
                        topics[i] = topics[i].trim();
                        tpc.add(topics[i]);

                        for (int indx = 0; indx < tpc.size(); indx++) {
                            textArea.append(tpc.get(indx)+"\n");
                        }

                    }

                    for(int si = 0; si < topicSentiment.length; si++) {
                        topicSentiment[si] = topicSentiment[si].trim();
                        topicsents.add(topicSentiment[si]);

                       for (int index = 0; index < topicsents.size(); index++) {
                          //  textArea.append(topicsents.get(index)+"\n");
                         System.out.print(topicsents+"\n");


                        }

                    }


                }


                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a file as `XSSFWorkbook`
2. Open a `XSSFSheet` of the workbook
3. Make some changes in the sheet. For example change the value of a `XSSFCell`
4. Save the changes by `workbook.write()`

---

## Example

```
// Open workbook and sheet
final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("filename.xlsx"));
final XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

// Iterate rows
final int firstRowNumber = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
final int lastRowNumber = sheet.getLastRowNum();
for (int rowNumber = firstRowNumber; rowNumber < lastRowNumber; rowNumber++ ) {
    final XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);

    if (row == null) continue;

    // Iterate columns
    final int firstColumnNumber = row.getFirstCellNum();
    final int lastColumnNumber = row.getLastCellNum();
    for (int columnNumber = firstColumnNumber; columnNumber < lastColumnNumber; columnNumber++ ) {
        final XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(firstColumnNumber);

        if (cell == null) continue;

        // Make some changes
        cell.setCellValue("new Value");
    }
}

// Save changes
workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("newFilename.xlsx"));
```